# HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are POST,DELETE,GET,HEAD

Tags: apex, workbench, patch

I have created a method to update the records in a case.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping= '/FieldCases/*')
global with sharing class RestCaseController {
    @HttpPatch
    global static String caseUpdate(String caseId, String caseStatus, String caseNote){
        Case companyCase = [SELECT Id, Subject, Status, Description FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];

        companyCase.Status = caseStatus;
        companyCase.Description += caseNote;
        update companyCase;

        Return 'Updated';
    }
}
```

and in work bench I am using

/services/apexrest/FieldCases

```
{"caseId" : "0037F00000bQYIjQAO",
 "caseStatus" : "Working",
 "caseNote" : "updating from the work bench"}
```

but I am getting the below error

HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are POST,DELETE,GET,HEAD

Comment: I think you need to pass CaseID also in URL. Like this : /services/apexrest/FieldCases/0037F00000bQYIjQAO

Comment: Thank you so much for responding but the error is still the same :(

Comment: @gs650x looks like issue with workbench. Can you try it in postman?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I tried it myself with workbench and it seems to be working for me, I am posting screenshots here:

[image: Apex class]

[image: Workbench result]

**API Version could be the issue in your case, Try changing your Apex class to latest api version.**