# HTTP patch not supported as a method

Tags: apex, rest

I am trying to integrate with a third party service, while trying to make a http request , i want to send PATCH as a method,I have looked for two solutions mentioned here in this question[How can I make a PATCH HTTP Callout from Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57215/how-can-i-make-a-patch-http-callout-from-apex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In both the solution , i get the exact same error like the one when i tried without the workarounds.**The requested resource was not found, or a disallowed method was used.**

The service is expecting PATCH as method ,not PUT nor POST and these workarounds are not overriding httpmethod as PATCH.

```
public class CRMOppUpdate{

public static void performUpdateOnOpportunity(){ 
    String strToken='';
    string scope='crm';
    strToken = BCDBJWToken.getBearerToken(scope);// Fetching Token
    system.debug('strToken '+strToken );
    Doc_Generator_Settings__c docGenSettings = Doc_Generator_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults(); // Custom Settings
    String apiKey =docGenSettings.Client_Id__c;
    STring SiebelEndpoint = docGenSettings.Endpoint_c;
    String requestBody= JSONGeneratorCRM.createJSON();
    system.debug('requestBody'+requestBody);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();   
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse responseString;
    string strEndpoint =SiebelEndpoint +'/opportunities/1-2DJLY2S?_HttpMethod=PATCH';

    system.debug('strEndpoint'+strEndpoint);               
    req.setEndPoint(strEndpoint);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer '+ strToken;
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    system.debug('authorizationHeader'+authorizationHeader);
    req.setHeader('API-Key',apiKey);
    req.setHeader('ApplicationId','CREDITS');
    req.setHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
    //req.setMethod('POST');
    PostMethod m = new PostMethod(strEndpoint+ '?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
    //req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'PATCH');         
    req.setBody(requestBody);
    req.setClientCertificateName('ABServices');

    req.setTimeout(120000);
    responseString = http.send(req);  
    system.debug('responseString'+responseString.getBody());


}
```

}

Comment: "It doesn't work" is rarely enough to determine a solution. Could you please edit your question to include a verbatim error message and line number, if any, or a detailed description of what negative behavior happens?

Comment: @DavidReed I updated my query , I hope its helpful now

Comment: In the link you mentioned, it says, not all server support the workaround. So if header `'X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH'` doesnt work then you have to use a middleware

Comment: Thanks you @PranayJaiswal i read it too, but needed to be sure before implementing it

Comment: Try below solution,below post is suggesting changing api version.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220244/http-method-patch-not-allowed-allowed-are-post-delete-get-head?rq=1 Thanks,
Rama